# How to enable specific cache names and disable other name using Caffeine cache in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache, caffeine-cache

I am using Spring Boot for my application. Using `@EnableCaching` annotation at application level.

Consider I have multiple cache names like below in some methods on the application

```
@Cacheable(value = "cache1")
@Cacheable(value = "cache2")
@Cacheable(value = "cache3")
@Cacheable(value = "cache4")
@Cacheable(value = "cache5")
```

My aim to cache only **cache1** for now. So defined following in application.properties

```
spring.cache.cache-names=cache1
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=100,expireAfterAccess=300s
```

But when I use the application, I get error like below as it can't find "cache2"

```
Cannot find cache named 'cache2' for Builder....
```

I have used multiple cache names in the application. Currently I want to use only **cache1** for now. Is it possible to say support only these cache names via some property? How to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the goal of this is, but maybe this is a way to do it:

You can define `String`-constants `CACHE_NAME_1` thru 5 somewhere and set them all to "cache1" at first. Use the constants in the `@Cacheable` as if you had really set it all up properly, so specify `CACHE_NAME_3` wherever it is supposed to be "cache3" in the end:

```
@Cacheable(CACHE_NAME_3)
```

Whenever you're ready, update the configuration, e.g.

```
spring.cache.cache-names=cache1,cache2
```

and assign "cache2" to whichever constant(s).

Rinse and repeat until "cache5".